# Custom activityIndicatorView takes time, while loading View

Tags: ios, multithreading, view, grand-central-dispatch

I want to load a view, but it takes forever to load so I tried to put an activityIndicatorView, but it starts to run when the view already loaded, and when I go back to the main view it's still running and it won't stop.

What do I have to do so that the activityIndicatorView starts just as soon as I hit the UIButton and stops when it finished loading?

I already tried all the similar questions her in stack overflow but non helped.

```
- (IBAction)boletin:(id)sender {

    UIImage *statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
    activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:statusImage];


    //Add more images which will be used for the animation
    activityImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"14.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"15.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"18.png"],
                                     nil];


    //Set the duration of the animation (play with it
    //until it looks nice for you)
    activityImageView.animationDuration = 0.7;


    //Position the activity image view somewhere in
    //the middle of your current view
    activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 25, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 75, 45, 45);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [activityImageView startAnimating];
        [self.view addSubview:activityImageView];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [activityImageView stopAnimating];
        });
    }); 

}
```

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: initialize and add images for activityImageView in viewdidload or loadview, your code allocate activityImageView every time in button click action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `startAnimating` on the image view, and adding it to your view hierarchy, off the main thread, which is going to be problematic. It's not clear from your code what, exactly, is blocking and requiring all this, but something like this should work for you:

```
// rest of your code is above here...
activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 25, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 75, 45, 45);
[self.view addSubview:activityImageView];
[activityImageView startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Do whatever is taking a long time here...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [activityImageView stopAnimating];
        [activityImageView removeFromSuperview];
    });
});
```